# "What it takes" usage

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Can I use "what it takes" when speaking about a company?
For example, "You should determine what it takes to get more clients."

Comment: Have  you looked up the idiom? [Do] what it takes to etc.

Comment: Why do you think you might not be able to use it about a company?

Comment: It seemed to me that it can be used only when we speak about a person.

Comment: When a company gets more clients, it may be because one or more persons have done work to make that happen.

Comment: ***what it takes*** is a relatively informal construction precisely equivalent to ***what[ever] is necessary / the requisite qualities*** (needed in order for some desirable outcome to be achieved). It does tend to imply "anthropomorphising" the subject - which isn't remotely problematic with, say, *This company has what it takes to be a global success*, but people might think it was a bit odd if you said something like *My kitchen has what it takes to cook a full English breakfast*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you should definitely put this comment as an answer here, seems you covered all the bases

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'See whether this car has what it takes to put the upmarket brands to shame in our unbiased Toyota Corolla review.' _Which_ (UK consumer guidance publication)

Comment: ' it's clear that Pesto Craft Kitchen has what it takes to win the hearts of pizza lovers everywhere.''

Comment: 'Whether it is for the home as a backup, or on a job site to power up tools and lights, or for any other purpose, this generator has what it takes.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***what it takes*** is a relatively informal construction precisely equivalent to ***what[ever] is necessary / the requisite qualities*** (needed in order for some desirable outcome to be achieved).

OP correctly recognizes that the usage *does* tend to imply "anthropomorphising" the subject. That's not remotely problematic with, say, ***This company** has what it takes to be a global success*, but people might think it was a bit odd if you said something like ***My kitchen** has what it takes to cook a full English breakfast*.

The *reason* for those associations of "anthropomorphisation" is probably just that we very often use the construction in contexts where the "necessary attributes" are human mental qualities, such as gritty determination, self-confidence, etc. Entities like *companies* can (figuratively?) manifest such attributes, but it's not so obvious how my example *kitchen* could do the same (it might well *contain* eggs, bacon, frying pan, etc., but a kitchen can't really be *resolutely determined* to prepare breakfast! :)

Comment: I only said *we very often use the construction in [such] contexts*. And even *that* extremely fine usage observation was only really justified by way of it being acknowledgement and response to *It seemed to [OP] that it can be used **only when we speak about a person***.

Comment: ...and in the unlikely event that I ever encountered / uttered the assertion *My kitchen has what it takes to cook a full English breakfast*, I would unhesitatingly classify it as at the very least *tending* towards "anthropomorphism"! :)

Comment: (Was above) Surely one could interpret 'what it takes' to mean 'the necessary attributes', with no necessity for these to be personal? A car has what it takes to climb a mountain road if the engine is powerful, and a kitchen, indeed, if it has the ingredients, utensils, and ingredients of a meal.

Answer (score 0):

It means the necessary skills, expertise, or qualities. In this case -- you should determine what is required to get more clients.